# How classes and nested classes are  instantiated in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have a non-static, class with 2 levels of nested classes inside.

```
public class A
{
     public class B
     {
         public class C{}
     }
}
```

How instances are created when I want to create:

- a) an instance of the master level class (new A())?
- b) an instance of the deepest level class (new C())?

What are performance and memory issues possible with such implementation?

Thanks!

Comment: "2 levels of subclasses inside" You mean the base class has members that are of its subclasses or something? Also, the title is pretty misleading, asking a general theoretical question when in fact it's about a specific scenario.

Comment: It would help if you showed a short piece of sample code

Comment: Master class, where did you take the term from?

Comment: @Hohhi - does it change a nature of the problem?

Comment: This has nothing to do with inheritance, by the way...

Comment: Corrent, someone edited it for me... so any idea?

Comment: Those aren't subclasses. Those are nested classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Java, a nested class in the CLR has no special properties that make it behave different from a class declared at namespace scope.  Layout and allocation behavior is identical.  It only affects scope.  The only advantage of nesting a class is that you can make it private.

Comment: Well, it does have "special" access in that a nested class is the only *different class* that can see the *private members* of the outer class. That's kinda special. (More formally: not only are the named private members of the outer class *in scope* inside the inner class, the inner class is *inside the accessibility domain* of the outer class members.)